# gganimate issue with geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I've been looking with envy and admiration at the various ggplot animations appearing on twitter since David Robinson released his gganimate package and thought I'd have a play myself. I am having an issue with gganimate when using geom_bar.  Hopefully the following example demonstrates the problem.

First generate some data for a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
                 y = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 z = c("A", "A", "B", "B"))
```

To demonstrate what I'm trying to do I thought it would be useful to plot an ordinary ggplot, facetted by `z`.  I'm trying to get gganimate to produce a gif that cycles between these 2 plots.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "Identity") +
   facet_grid(~z)
```

[image: facetted_barchart]

But when I use gganimate the plot for B behaves oddly.  In the second frame the bars start at the values that the first frame's bars finish at, rather than starting at the origin. As if it was a stacked bar chart.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, frame = z)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "Identity") 
gg_animate(p)
```

[image: bars_animation]

Incidentally when trying the same plot with `geom_point` everything works as expected.

```
q <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, frame = z)) +
    geom_point() 
gg_animate(q)
```

I tried to post some images, but apparently I don't have sufficient reputation, so I hope it makes sense without them.  Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is that without faceting, the bars are stacked. Use `position = "identity"`:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, frame = z)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Identity", position = "identity") 
gg_animate(p)
```

[image]

In order to avoid confusion in situations like this, it is  much more useful to replace `frame` by `fill` (or `colour`, depending on the geom you are using`):

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Identity") 
p
```

[image]

The two plots that are drawn, when you replace `fill` by `frame` correspond exactly to *exclusively* drawing one of the colours at a time.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!